# OSX cocoa detecting a monitor removal or addition

Tags: macos, cocoa, monitor

I'm looking for a event that will tell me if someone added/remove a monitor on OSX.   I was looking at the NSScreen class but I'm not seeing anything there. NSScreen does have a NSScreenColorSpaceDidChangeNotification
but I don't think that will do what I want it to. I'm not coming up with much with a google search.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CGDisplayRegisterReconfigurationCallback](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/Quartz_Services_Ref/#//apple_ref/c/func/CGDisplayRegisterReconfigurationCallback) lets you register a function to be called when displays are changed.